# Azure Cloud no matches for kind "SecretProviderClass" in version "secrets-store.csi.k8s.io/v1alpha1"

Tags: azure, azure-security, azure-secrets

I am working in azure cloud and wanted to add a simple ServiceProviderClass using the doc from Azure [Azure /
secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure](https://github.com/Azure/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/blob/master/examples/v1alpha1_secretproviderclass_service_principal.yaml)  replacing the `secret`, `keyvaultName` and `tenantId`

```yaml
apiVersion: secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: SecretProviderClass
metadata:
  name: azure-kvname
spec:
  provider: azure
  parameters:
    usePodIdentity: "false"         # [OPTIONAL] if not provided, will default to "false"
    keyvaultName: "kvname"          # the name of the KeyVault
    cloudName: ""          # [OPTIONAL for Azure] if not provided, azure environment will default to AzurePublicCloud 
    objects:  |
      array:
        - |
          objectName: secret1
          objectType: secret        # object types: secret, key or cert
          objectVersion: ""         # [OPTIONAL] object versions, default to latest if empty
    tenantId: "tid"                    # the tenant ID of the KeyVault
```

And when I try to apply it to my cluser using the Azure Cloud Bash:

```sh
hacker@Azure:~$ kubectl apply -f secrets-provider.yaml
error: unable to recognize "secrets-provider.yaml.yaml": no matches for kind "SecretProviderClass" in version "secrets-store.csi.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
```

It seems to be that kind and version are incompatible eventhough they are everywhere on the doc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is actually really simple, the `secret-store-csi-driver` was not yet install. Thus it was not recognized. Basically make sure you follow the [pre-requisistes](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/secrets-store-csi-driver/blob/master/charts/secrets-store-csi-driver/README.md).

From the Azure Cloud Terminal you can use Helm to install the driver:

```sh
helm repo add secrets-store-csi-driver https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/secrets-store-csi-driver/master/charts
helm install csi-secrets-store secrets-store-csi-driver/secrets-store-csi-driver
```

> There is an ongoing issue with the driver [secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure#259](https://github.com/Azure/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure/issues/259), for azure you need to explicitly specify `--grpc-supported-providers=azure`

And now it works:

```sh
hacker@Azure:~$ kubectl apply -f secrets-provider.yaml
secretproviderclass.secrets-store.csi.x-k8s.io/azure-kvname created
hacker@Azure:~$ kubectl get SecretProviderClass
NAME           AGE
azure-kvname   39s
```

Hopefully that will help.